# Update model instance by another user but keep originator name unchanged in Django

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am learning and working on particular project, where I am allowing few users in the same model (initiator, reviewer and approver) to update model by using model.forms during the different state (initiation (draft), review and approval).
I have no issue on initiation stage as the originator is the same user who does model update. problem which I am struggling appears to happen during review and approval stages which makes my model updated however originator name is replaced by another user if I call:

```
 def update_eq(request, pk):
    
         ___rest of the code___
    
            if eq.eq_status == 'Draft':      
               form = EqForm(request.POST or None, instance=eq)
                    if form.is_valid():
                            eq.initiator = request.user                    
                            form.save()
    
        ___rest of the code___
```

[Solution] Based on Willem's comment my updated view...

```
           elif eq.eq_status == 'Review':      
              form = EqForm(request.POST or None, instance=eq)
                if form.is_valid():
                    # eq.initiator = request.user                    
                    form.save()

        ___rest of the code___
```

However, once I change the state i.e. move to Review or Approve stage and making same update i.e. calling to save form, I am getting the initiator field updated with 'None' value.

Is there any way I allow non-initiator to update the model, but keep model original initiator as current initiator still?

Comment: remove the `eq.initiator = request.user` logic

Comment: Thanks Willem! All works fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *editing* the `Eq` instance, so that means the instance is already created and thus the `initiator` does not need to be set/updated. You thus can remove the `eq.initiator = request.user` line(s) in your view:

```
def update_eq(request, pk):
    # rest of the code …
    if eq.eq_status == 'Draft':
        form = EqForm(request.POST or None, instance=eq)
        if form.is_valid():
            # no eq.initiator = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thanks Willem again! I have implemented this! Thanks for helping to me!